# Please compare two code snippets and explain why one work and another not

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

first snippet(does not work)

configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class UiConfig {
    @Bean //if i doesn't write this bean  result will not change
    ApplicationWebListener getApplicationWebListener(){
        return new ApplicationWebListener();
    }
}
```

listener:

```
@WebListener
public class ApplicationWebListener implements ServletContextListener {
    @Autowired
    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("ServletContextListener destroyed");
    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("ServletContextListener started");
        databaseHelper.fillEmptyTables();
    }
}
```

result:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.epam.hhsystem.web.controllers.ApplicationWebListener.contextInitialized(ApplicationWebListener.java:24)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4887)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5381)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

second snippet:

configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class UiConfig {
    @Bean//if I doesn't write this bean MyApplicationListener code doesn't execute
    MyApplicationListener getMyApplicationListener(){
        return new MyApplicationListener();
    }
}
```

listener:

```
public class MyApplicationListener implements
        ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    @Autowired
    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {

        databaseHelper.fillEmptyTables();
    }

}
```

result - method invokes and good works.

DatabaseHelper:

```
@Component    
public class DatabaseHelper {
        @Autowired
        UtilService utilService;

        public  void fillEmptyTables(){
            if(!isSkillsInDatabase()){
                utilService.addGeneratedSkill();
            }
            if(!isEventTypesInDatabase()){
                utilService.addGeneratedEventType();
            }
            if(!isEventStatusesInDatabase()){
                utilService.addGeneratedEventStatus();
            }

        }
        public  boolean isSkillsInDatabase(){
            return utilService.getAllSkills().size() != 0; 
        }
        public  boolean isEventStatusesInDatabase(){
            return utilService.getAllEventStatuses().size() != 0; 
        }
        public  boolean isEventTypesInDatabase(){
            return utilService.getAllEventTypes().size() != 0; 
        }
    }
```

Can you explain me these situations?

Answer (score 1):

Look at your stack trace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.epam.hhsystem.web.controllers.ApplicationWebListener.contextInitialized(ApplicationWebListener.java:24)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4887)
```

The listener is started by the container. The `@WebListener` annotation tells the `Servlet` container to instantiate your `ApplicationWebListener` class. **This is not a Spring managed bean.** Therefore, Spring does not autowire anything into it and the `DatabaseHelper` field remains `null`.

This bean

```
@Bean //if i doesn't write this bean  result will not change
ApplicationWebListener getApplicationWebListener(){
    return new ApplicationWebListener();
}
```

will remain in your context and **not be used at all by the container** since it isn't registered with the container.

Your second code snippet is a completely unrelated use case.

Comment: `Your second code snippet is a completely unrelated use case.` what does it mean? it is good or bad?

Comment: @gstackoverflow That's up to your use case. The purpose of Spring's `ApplicationListener` is to react to **Spring events**, not container events.

Comment: I understood you. What best way to react on *container events* ?

Comment: I need catch event when all  beans are autowiring

Comment: @gstackoverflow There is no _best_ way. The `Servlet` api has a number of listeners for different types of events. If you need to register Spring managed beans as listeners, use the `WebApplicationInitializer` interface to register them.

Comment: What method of WebApplicationInitializer  I need override?

Comment: @gstackoverflow The interface only has one method...Please read the javadoc. Start doing some research of your own.

Comment: I read about it. everywhere override onStartup method. I need to @ auowired my bean to class which implements WebApplicationInitializer and invoke  required method in onStartup method ???

Comment: @gstackoverflow Read the javadoc and the Spring documentation on how to use it.